# Passbook adding href

Tags: passbook

I'd like to create a Passbook card with a URL on the back page in one of the "Back fields".  Does anyone know if it's possible to use a href entry so that I don't expose the actual URL?

For example, in the JSON record, instead of:

```
"value" : "Click here, http://google.com.au"
```

make it:

```
"value" : "Click here, <a href='http://google.com.au'>HERE</a>"
```

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot, any html markup field will be parsed.

Urls are parsed automatically and must be in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

@MacTeo is correct, URLs (emails, telephone numbers and addresses) will automatically become clickable, but the any HTML markup will be not be processed and you'll end up with the raw HTML visible on the back of the pass.

The best you can do right now is to get hold of a short domain and install a redirect script.

Then you can use something short but enticing such as `http://wt.is/latest_offer` that redirects to wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS7 on you can use the `attributed_value` property for this. ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/FieldDictionary.html)):

`"attributedValue": "<a href='http://example.com/customers/123'>Edit my profile</a>"`